# Regex to extract text after a pattern

Tags: regex, text-extraction

I am trying to extract the Error Messages from loader output like below :

```
LOADER_ERROR : *** Failure The UserId, Password or Account is invalid., attempts:1
LOADER_ERROR : *** Time out waiting for a response.
```

Expected Output :

```
Failure The UserId, Password or Account is invalid., attempts:1
Time out waiting for a response.
```

With the below regex, I am able to extract everything after the last occurrence of ': ' character.

```
  .+(\:\s.+)$
```

Output :

```
: *** Failure The UserId, Password or Account is invalid., attempts:1
: *** Time out waiting for a response.
```

How do I strip ': ' or '*** ' at the beginning from the output ?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are including the `:` and `***` that's in the group so they will come in the output.
This should work:

```
.+\:\s\W+(.+)$
```

[Check its demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/kInbty/1/)

Answer (score 3):

The data that you want seems to be after the first colon. You can match all before the first colon using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

Note that you don't have to escape `\:`

```
^[^:]+:\W*(.+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:]+:` Match 1+ times any char except `:`, then match `:`
- `\W*` Optionally match non word charcters
- `(.+)` Capture in group 1, matching 1+ times any char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8tFCc8/1)

---

If the format of the data is always like that, a more strict pattern could be matching 3 times an asterix and start the capture group with matching a word character.

```
^\w+\s+:\s+\*{3}\s+(\w.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6wo1YF/1)